# How to keep an application active in background

Tags: android

I am writing an application which can continuously monitor the input from mic, process it (Processing algorithms are written in C++) and save (log) or playback some events of interests. I am testing my app on Android L and Android M phones.

Application works fine as per my requirement with issue in following use case:

1. Turn the monitoring on
2. Press home button to send the app in background
3. Ensure device is not charging
4. Wait for some time

After some time (About 15 min) I get following message in logcat:

> Suspending all threads...

To overcome the problem I tried following:

1. Hold wake locks (PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)
2. Use another level of thread spawning using an asynctask
3. Set FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in my activity

But none of them seem to work. On iOS I can achieve the desired functionality of this use case using highlighted flag in infoplist.

[image]

Is it possible to do something similar in Android? (I believe audio players already do something similar)

Comment: "`How to keep an application active in background`" No you cannot do that. You can make a service with `START_STICKY` but that would restart as well once system needs resources.

Comment: @SharpEdge Thanks for the service point. I will do that. Can android also restart musicplayer apps in background?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know because i have not made or used any music player apps except for the stock ones. You can google it though. There must be a work around as how the music apps work as service.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this won't be a complete solution for you. But i will try to give a solution that will extend the lifetime of your application. First of all it is not possible to keep an application alive all the time. It is against the Android's rule, as when the system needs resource (for foreground app) it may stop your application. But you can extend the life time of an app by pushing the functionality into the service. Below is a solution for you.

1. Create an Activity which has 2 button to start and stop recording.
2. Create a Service and place a Public static variable as a flag set to either true or false.
3. In activity use the above static field to check if the service is active or not and enable or disable the start recording button according to it.
4. Use the button to start the service, inside the service acquire a Partial Wake Lock and start a Thread and do your recording. I hope you don't want to redeliver your Intent to the service as it is used to just start a thread for recording. You can use START_NOT_STICKY which restarts the service only if there is a pending start call. If you really wanted to redeliver your intent with recording and append it with the new one, i would say it is point less as you don't know when the service would be restarted and you may miss some recording at that time.
5. As you hold the partial wake lock it will continue to run until the Foreground app needs resource. As the service has higher priority than the background app.
6. In onDestroy()Stop the Thread by using the interrupt flag (Save recording too by checking the interrupt flag), set the public static field to FALSE and release the wake lock. You may start the recording from your activity when this is done.

By using FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in your activity you are just telling the system to "Keep the screen on when i am in this activity". If you hit home or switch to another activity it will not work. I hope games or apps like video players use this to keep the screen on.

I should also point that by keeping the Partial Wake Lock for longer time it may drain your battery considerably. Also you could advice your users to stay in the activity for continuous recording if you use the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON.

I would although advice to Start an Intent Service, acquire a partial wake lock and start recording. As it will stops the overhead for creating a new thread and starting or stopping it when needed.

Also in iOS, I think the system GC the APP for resources when your application shifts to the background. That's what i remember when i was learning iOS.

I hope my solution helped you little bit to extend your application's life time. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, this is useful